# how to reset Joomla admin password from the shell?

Tags: database-administration, joomla

any idea how I can reset/change Joomla admin password from the linux command line? I have root access to the box.

I don't think I can do it phpMyAdmid way.

I don't know where the Joomla db is located and how I can connect to it.

### Update

I found `configuration.php` that tells me the db name, host (local) and db prefix. But I don't know the password. I am receiving `ERROR 1045 (28000): Access denied for user 'edumate_joomla'@'localhost' (using password: NO)`

Comment: the db password (if there is one) should be in that configuration.php file as well.

Comment: the password was not in the configuration.php file but a colleague of mine knew the password (was sick yesterday) so everything is solved

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I usually do this type of thing by inserting a known password hash directly into whatever database you're using with joomla. Assuming you have ample privileges on the database, you should be able to do this through either the CLI or phpMyAdmin.

I am not familiar with Joomla's database schema, but there should be something like a "users" table. Inside of that table, there should be a "password" column, containing password hashes, one for each user. You should be able to replace the password hash for your admin user with a known-good hash, either from a different Joomla install or from another Joomla user.

Comment: the thing is that I do not know where the database is on the hard drive and how I can connect to it via phpMyAdmin. Maybe it is not even installed

Comment: If Joomla is running (not throwing errors) then you're connected to a database. It's most likely you're running a MySQL database. You're going to need to research how to use the MySQL command line and how to execute queries against your Joomla database.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a link to documentation on how to reset the password. You must have root access to MySQL:

http://docs.joomla.org/How_you_reset_an_administrator_password%3F

Comment: Welcome to Server Fault! Generally we like answers on the site to be able to stand on their own - Links are great, but if that link ever breaks the answer should have enough information to still be helpful. Please consider editing your answer to include more detail. See the [FAQ](http://www.serverfault.com/faq) for more info.